# How to authorize Spotify using Angular

Tags: angularjs, api, spotify

I am trying to use Spotify's API to get just song and artist information. I do not want any user info. Right now I have created my application and gotten my client id and client secret. I am not using a server (node) for this project and I am just wanting to use Angular's $http request to get different information.

I am confused as to how I get to that point with authorization. Most of the docs that I have read are telling me to use something like this...

```
GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=34fFs29kd09
```

Then for normal requests I use this type of URL..

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases
```

I think I just need to know how to store my authorization so I can pull requests like this and is there a way to do this in say Postman so I can see the actually data that I am pulling in?

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to get data from Spotify without having to hook up a user account like you are able to with itunes?

Comment: near the bottom of the document, it describes how to get data without a user login;  it essentially requires the app owner to have a user account that has gone through the authorization code flow and obtained an access token and refresh token, then the app refreshing the access token when it expires.